# how prevent EF for sending extra delete sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

Here is my database:
 [image: db1]

[image: db2]

[image: db3]

i have set `OnDelete:Cascade` for `articleId` relation between two tables. so when we delete a record from article table sql will delete all article pictures from articlePics table. i am using EF for deleting rows from my database, when i use this code :

```
 db.article_table.Remove(article);
```

EF sends N+1 delete query to database ( 1 for removing article & N for removing pictures ).
when using code below :

```
  db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

EF sends 1 delete query and N Update query to database ( 1 for removing article & N for setting articlePics_table `articleId` col to null ).

how can i remove an article with one delete query and let SQL itself remove childs with `OnDelete:Cascade` ?

### update 1

i am using database first approach and here is my connection string and `OnModelCreating`:

```
      <add name="educationSocialNetworkEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/db.csdl|res://*/db.ssdl|res://*/db.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=educationSocialNetwork;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

---

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any map fluent configuration?

Comment: You don't answer @AlbertoMonteiro's question. How do you map the association in the context? You should tell EF that it's cascading.

Comment: @GertArnold i updated my question , is that correct now ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like this in your fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>
   .HasMany(a => a.articlePics)
   .WithRequired(a => a.Article)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: should i do this for all my 40 tables ??

Comment: For the ones you need cascading on delete yes. But didn't entity framework add this automatically when you created the models with Database first? Or did you add the cascading later with ssms?

Comment: But didn't entity framework add this automatically when you created the models with Database first? No it didnt , did you add the cascading later with ssms? No ,  recreating EF model will  solve the problem ??

Comment: I thought EF database first added it automatically yes, just test it quickly with a new project I guess, takes 5 minutes to do :)